# Как сделать телефонный вызов из приложения

Tags: java, android

Нашел кучу примеров которые работают с помощью Intent, т.е вызывается стандартная звонилка и туда копируется номер и дальше просто нужно нажать на кнопку вызова.

Как реализовать приложение которое само производит телефонный вызов?

PS. Извиняюсь если вопрос звучит не совсем ясно.

```
Uri call = Uri.parse("7777777777"); 
Intent surf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, call); 
startActivity(surf);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:900..." ));
startActivity(intent);
```

а это в прописать в `Manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Если же вы хотите что бы ваше приложение откликалось `scheme:tel` в `Manifest.xml` нужно добавить следующие строки:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
```

И если я не ошибаюсь, вы можете заменить схему на свою, на пример, `scheme:customScheme` и тогда вызов будет следующим:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("customScheme:900..." ));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь то в данном примере будет вызываться всетаки звонилка которая выбрана по дефолту в Android, а мне нужно что бы именно мое приложение выполняло вызов абонента.

Comment: похоже неправильно понял вопрос, я обновил ответ.